# Pick Image From Android Device's Gallery App

Tags: android, android-intent, gallery

In my android application, I implemented a feature to pick an image from Gallery. For that earlier I was doing this-

```
Intent pickImageIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
pickImageIntent.setType("image/*");
startActivityForResult(pickImageIntent, GALLERY_REQUEST_CODE);
```

By doing this, a dialog with all available image source application like Dropbox including Native Gallery app were displayed and it asks to choose one. Then I changed to

```
Intent pickImageIntent = new   Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
pickImageIntent.setType("image/*");
startActivityForResult(pickImageIntent, GALLERY_REQUEST_CODE);
```

By doing this most of applications were not diplayed but still some like Picasa are diplayed. I want to pick an image from Device's native gallery app only or we can say from either device's internal or external memory not from any third party application.

If any one has solution for this please help me with that.

Answer (score 2):

> To pick image from Gallery only

```
Intent pickImageIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
pickImageIntent.setType("image/*"); 
startActivityForResult(pickImageIntent, GALLERY_REQUEST_CODE);
```

Comment: works , @Suresh remove second parameter from Intent constructor